# How do I get blogger SOHO theme to look non-responsive on ipad and desktop?

Tags: html, css, blogger

I am a new beginner in blogging and I am using Bloggers new theme SOHO. I like everything except for the fact that when I am looking my blog from ipad I can not see the whole menu that is placed under the head titels text (and not in my sidebar). That is really annoying. So I would like to expand the width to the header and footer of my blog but not nessesary the posts...or to make it look non-responsive. (Hmm...I do not know if google will like that..?)

(I have seen other Blogger SOHO users having their blogs looking non-responsive on desktops and ipads but unfortunately I do not receive answers to how they did it.)

Can anyone help me expand widths or make it look non-responsive?

Answer (score 0):

Its mean your media query is working, try to change it through css, find 
`@media screen and (max-width: 767px) /* for example */`
767px is viewport width, change that px maybe help your question